# Keep numbers as phone number alignment in string textAlignment

Tags: swift, alignment

Suppose I have a string contains numbers as a Phone number and I want to set `textAligment = .right` and keep the phone number as is.

For example:

```
let phone = "0-(500)-100-200"
let string = "\(phone) more information"
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
cell.textLabel?.text = string
```

**Output**

200-100-(500)-0 more information

**Expected**

0-(500)-100-200 more information

Any hint on that?

Comment: Can you show as an image what you want it to look like? Also when you want it to look like that?

Comment: I just pasted your code into the Master detail template in Xcode and got exactly what you say you expected, ie. "0-(500)-100-200 more information"

Comment: @Magnas Could you please try if you have `cell.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft`

Comment: Yes, still getting exactly the same.

Comment: In a playground this `import UIKit; let textLabel = UILabel(); let phone = "0-(500)-100-200"; let string = "\(phone) more information"; textLabel.textAlignment = .right;textLabel.text = string; print(textLabel.text!)` prints the expected output `0-(500)-100-200 more information`

Comment: show your whole code, somewhere you must be using `.reversed()` on the phone...

Comment: @Magnas Even if you replace more information to RTL language?

Comment: @Do2 Actually, `reversed()` will reverse the number totally

Comment: you are right-ignore my comment :)

Comment: @Magnas can you please try `let string = "\(phone) هيلو";`

Comment: @A.K.M. I get the small text string "هيلو" followed by "100-200-(500)-0"

Comment: @Magnas This is the issue exactly, I just make a UILabel to be in `cell.accessoryView` instead